# -Ywarn-value-discard is not reported in some cases

Tags: scala

In scalac help, it is said that `-Ywarn-value-discard` should warn when expression returns non-Unit but that result is unused:

```
$ scalac -Y
-Ywarn-value-discard          Warn when non-Unit expression results are unused.
```

But when I compile the following file:

```
// compile with scalac -Ywarn-value-discard Main.scala
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    hasReturnValue()
    println("hello") // this line silences the warning
  }
  def hasReturnValue() = {
    System.currentTimeMillis()
  }
}
```

I get no warning, though in my understanding `hasReturnValue()` is an expression, it has non-Unit result, and that result is definitely unused.

Looking at Scala Language Specification, I find that spec says slightly different thing:

```
Value Discarding
If e has some value type and the expected type is Unit, e is converted to the expected type by embedding it in the term { e; () }.
```

Seems that wording in help text for `-Ywarn-value-discard` is a little incorrect.

I agree that per specification my example does not contain value discarding, but is there a warning that will catch all unused returns?

Comment: Try the "NonUnitStatements" rule from WartRemover